# How to show the path of a workout using Facebook Open Graph Stories in iOS - Result is different on Facebook App versus iPhone Browser

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this code to share workout data on Facebook. My intention is to eventually show a path of the run/walk. But I have this confusion at the moment. If I execute this code and look at my Facebook page on either iOS Facebook App, or any browser on a computer (Mac for example) I see only the distance and some other information. But when I look at my post on a browser on an iOS device (logged in my Facebook account on either Safari or Chrome on iPhone) I see a map (See images attached). My question is why is there a difference on the look of the post depending on how I view it? And how can I show the map on the post to the Facebook App? I am using the latest Facebook SDK for iOS: Version 4.28.0

```
   func shareOnFacebook () {
    // Create an object
    let properties = ["og:type": "fitness.course",
                      "og:title": "Title",
                      "og:description": "Description",
                      "fitness:duration:value": 1200,
                      "fitness:duration:units": "s",
                      "fitness:distance:value": 4.3,
                      "fitness:distance:units": "mi",
                      "fitness:metrics:location:latitude": 36.9926439,
                      "fitness:metrics:location:longitude": -102.0419088,
                      "fitness:metrics:location:altitude" :42,
                      "fitness:metrics:timestamp" :"2017-11-18T00:00",
                      "fitness:metrics:distance:value" : 0,
                      "fitness:metrics:distance:units":"mi" ,
                      "fitness:metrics:pace:value" :0,
                      "fitness:metrics:pace:units" :"s/m",
                      "fitness:metrics:calories":0] as [String : Any]

    let object = FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject(properties: properties)

    // Create an action
    let action = FBSDKShareOpenGraphAction()
    action.actionType = "fitness.run"
    action.setObject(object, forKey: "fitness:course")

    // Create the content
    let content = FBSDKShareOpenGraphContent()
    content.action = action
    content.previewPropertyName = "fitness:course"

    let shareDialog = FBSDKShareDialog()
    shareDialog.fromViewController = self
    shareDialog.shareContent = content
    if shareDialog.canShow() {
        shareDialog.show()
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]